# can not print address of a pointer in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new in c++. I wrote this program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int x=24;
    char y='A';
    char* pchar=&y;
    int* pint=&x;

    cout <<"pchar= "<<hex<<&pchar<<endl;
    cout <<"pint = "<<hex<<&pint<<endl;
    cout <<endl;
    cout <<"pchar= "<<hex<<pchar<<endl;
    cout <<"pint = "<<hex<<pint<<endl;

    pchar=NULL;
    pint=NULL;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

and its result 
[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzxp1tkuqgw5p3g/Screenshot%202014-02-18%2022.52.29.png]

Can you help me to understand why I can't print the address of variables without `&`?
I think `pchar` is already the address of `y`.

thanks

Comment: y is only a character, it is not a null terminated string, So A.... is due to rubbish after the 'A' till it finds a null.

Answer (score 6):

When you use a `char*` (like your variable `pchar`) the [string overload of `operator<<` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) is used, and when treating it as a string it will print characters until it find the string terminator character (`'\0'`). Unfortunately in this case `pchar` points only to a single character, so you have *undefined behavior* as the function goes out looking for characters in memory not allocated to you.

To print a pointer you have to cast it to `void*`:

```
std::cout << "pchar = " << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<void*>(pchar) << '\n';
```

It works when you print the address of the variable `pchar` (when you print `&pchar`) because then the type of the expression is of type `char**` which have no direct overload, and instead uses the generic pointer overload (case 7 in [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)).

Comment: Note that `std::hex` is permanent. So, you might want to switch back to `std::dec` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Operator << treated char* as a string. But you can change your code to following

```
cout <<"pchar= "<<hex<<(void*)pchar<<endl;
```

It should work.
I cannot access std code now, but cout implementation should contain something like this

```
operator << (char* char_ptr)
{
    //interpret char * as pointer to null-terminated string
    ... code to output string
}
```

So there is impossible to print char* as address without casting to something.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the `int` cast, as there's no guarantee an address will fit into an `int`.

Comment: Like Fred says, don't cast a pointer to `int`. Remember that on most 64-bit systems `int` is still 32 bits while pointers are 64 bits. *If* you want to use a type that is big enough for both an `int` and any pointer, use `intptr_t`.

Comment: Still can't upvote this because you don't say *why* the `char*` is treated as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need

```
cout <<"pchar= "<<hex<<static_cast<void*>(pchar)<<endl;
```

to print the value of `pchar` (not its address, that would be the address of the variable `pchar`, not the address to which it points to).

It behaves like this because `std::ostream` (`cout`'s type) has an overloaded `operator<<` which takes a `char*` and treats it specifically to print out a string.

Comment: What is the effect of `hex` on printing a pointer value? On my system, it prints in hex either way. In fact, I tried `oct` and it still printed in hex.

Comment: @FredLarson copy-paste.

Comment: Fair enough, but is it safe to say that `std::hex` has no effect on printing pointer values?

Comment: @FredLarson: Yes, it is safe to say that. `std::hex` should only affect integers, which pointers are not. Also, the hexadecimal representation that you see when you print out a void pointer is just a convention, albeit a common one. They do not necessarily have to print out like that.

Answer (score 1):

Change this statement

```
cout <<"pchar= "<<hex<<pchar<<endl;
```

to

```
cout <<"pchar= "<<hex<< ( const void * )pchar<<endl;
```

The problem is that when you write this way

```
cout <<"pchar= "<<hex<<pchar<<endl;
```

the compiler considers pchar as an address of the first element of a string and tries to output this string. There is an overloaded operator << for type `char *` and it is called in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`pchar` value is address of `y`. So if you print `pchar` it will print address of `y`. `&pchar`, it will print address of `pchar`. Remember `pchar` also have some address.

Comment: This does not explain the output the OP got. That would just mean getting a wrong/unexpected address displayed, not the garbage in the picture linked in the question.

Comment: @Hulk OP has edited his question afterwards I think.

Comment: The link was there from the beginning, just the markup got fixed to have it embedded.