# std::cout << cstring; prints value of cstring elements, not cstring hex address. Why?

Tags: c++, arrays, cout, c-strings

I understand that an array of chars is different to a cstring, due to the inclusion of a suffixing \0 sentinel value in a cstring. 
However, I also understand that, in the case of a cstring, an array of chars, or any other type of array, the array identifier in the program is a pointer to the array.
So, below is perfectly valid.

```
char some_c_string[] = "stringy";
char *stringptr;
stringptr = some_c_string; // assign pointer val to other pointer
```

What I don't understand is why `std::cout` automatically assumes I want to output the value of each element in either a cstring, or an array of chars, rather than the hex address. For example:

```
char some_c_string[] = "stringy"; // got a sentinel val
char charArray[5] = {'H','e','l','l','o'}; // no space for sentinel val \0
char *stringptr;
stringptr = some_c_string;
int intArray[3] = {1, 2, 4}; 

cout << some_c_string << endl << charArray << endl
     << stringptr << endl << intArray << endl;
```

Will result in the output:

`stringy
Hello
stringy
0xsomehexadd`

So for the cstring and the char array, `std::cout` has given me the value of each element, rather than the hex address like with the int array. 
I guess this became a standard in C++ for convenience. But can someone please expand on 1) When this became standard. 2) How `std::cout` differentiates between char/cstrings and other arrays. I guess it uses `sizeof()` to see it's is an array of single bytes, and that value of each array element is an ASCII int value to identify an array of chars/cstring.

Thanks! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can not print address of a pointer in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858970/can-not-print-address-of-a-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing fancy going on. The `operator<<` has a special overload for `char*`, so that you can do `std::cout << "Hello World";`.  It's been like that since day 1 of c++.

For anything besides `char*`, the pointer address is displayed as hex.
If you want to display the address of a `char*`, simply cast it to `void*`, ie

```
std::cout << (void*)"Hello World";
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that `std::cout << charArray;` is undefined behavior because there is no terminating null character in the string.

Comment: Proper casting  should be `static_cast<const void*>("Hello World")` ... but given that you are printing out virtual memory addresses, you are obviously in hacker mode and not in clean C++ mode, and that is a lot of extra typing!